# Multiple Stores using React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to connect multiple stores on a component. I tried the example on the docs: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store, but throw errors when create Context:
**Error**
`Context<{ onSession: boolean; }>' is not assignable to type 'Context<ReactReduxContextValue<any, AnyAction>>'.`

And if I use only the compose without Context, does not recognize the component:
**Error**
`JSX element type 'Main' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

*Has someone knows how to connect multiple stores?*

This is how the implementation is going:

*index.tsx*

```
  const initialA = {
    onSession: false
  };

  const ContextA = React.createContext(initialA);
  const store = configureStoreSession();

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="app-container">
        <Provider store={store} context={ContextA}>
          <Covenants />
        </Provider>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

*main.tsx*

```
type MainProps = {
  onSession: boolean;
};

function Main({ onSession }: MainProps) {
return (
    <div>Has session? {onSession}</div>
)
}

const mapStateA = (state: AppStateA) => {
  return {
    filters: state.stateA.filters
  };
};

const mapStateB = (state: AppStateB) => {
  return {
    onSession: state.stateB.onSession
  };
};

const mapDispatchA = {};
const mapDispatchB = {};

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateA, mapDispatchA),
  connect(mapStateB, mapDispatchB)
)(Main);
```

Comment: Not an exact solution but a similar issue is tackled here(in Svelte) ->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72552107/svelte-multiple-app-instances-with-stores-without-redux/72552108#72552108

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* read multiple stores in one component (except in extremely rare edge cases), and [you *should not* be creating multiple stores for your application](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#can-or-should-i-create-multiple-stores-can-i-import-my-store-directly-and-use-it-in-components-myself).

If you can add more details on what actual problem you're trying to solve, I may be able to add additional detail to help.  Otherwise, please don't try to do this - it's the wrong approach.

Comment: While it is NOT considered best practice to create multiple stores for your application, there are cases where that it is necessary.

I'm working on a legacy project, where the Redux Store is a complete mess of spaghetti.  Items that should be in local state are in the Store via reducers added at runtime, selectors are a nested mess, values are randomly Immutable or not... 

To pay down the technical debt, we're creating a new store using @reduxjs/toolkit and slowly migrating over.  Until that's done, we need two stores.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import rootReducer from './slices/rootReducer';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware()]
});

const storeContext = createContext<ReactReduxContextValue>({store, storeState: rootReducer});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the idea was to do something like this:
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRa4j.png)

Session Store could share with the apps below, but the way that I solved it was using spa architecture and the library: https://single-spa.js.org/. So like every app register as independent I can have multiple stores, and for the sessions variables I used sessionStorage.

Answer (score 0):

It will be much easier by using hooks instead of using connect HOC.

As described [here](https://www.geekyhub.in/post/handling-multiple-stores-in-react-redux-application/), you can create selector hooks and dispatch hooks for your stores and then use them in any component throughout the application.

```js
export const useStore1Dispatch = createDispatchHook(store1Context);
export const useStore1Selector = createSelectorHook(store1Context);

export const useStore2Dispatch = createDispatchHook(store2Context);
export const useStore2Selector = createSelectorHook(store2Context);
```

If you still have to use `connect`, with [`compose`](https://redux.js.org/api/compose). Then you should keep in mind that methods/values with similar names in another store will be overridden. In your codebase, I see that you haven't passed the context to connect call which is necessary for the store which is not using default react-redux context.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the real requirement is render a react-native APP as a sub-app (library) in other APP, right? If so, you can see how I implement it in [let other react-native APP can embed PixelShapeRN as sub-app](https://github.com/flyskywhy/PixelShapeRN/commit/9728e45ffe4a5046d7cd8076b2b103c5eef079c5), which ref to [Isolating Redux Sub-Apps](https://redux.js.org/usage/isolating-redux-sub-apps) and [Breaking out of Redux paradigm to isolate apps](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/eeee2f619620ab7b55673a4ee2bf8400)